# Minimum and maximum frequency in a system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Defining the Fourier transform of a function $f(x):\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$\hat f(k) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-ikx}dx.$$
In [this paper on Optimized Schwarz Method](http://www.ddm.org/DD12/Gander.pdf), the authors mention a bounded range of frequencies $k$ when the domain is bounded and discrete. Page 19:

> Since real computations are performed on bounded domains and discretized operators,the range of the frequency parameter k is not arbitrary. It is bounded from below by a lowest frequency dependent on the size of the domain in y direction and the boundary conditions imposed, $k^2> k^2_{min}$ and from above, $k$ is bounded by the mesh size $h$ in y direction, $k^2<k^2_{max}:=(\frac\pi h)^2$.

In this case, $f$ is defined in $R^2$ and we take the Fourier transform w.r.t. the variable $y$.

I can understand why $k$ is bounded from above by $\frac\pi h$, taking the discrete Fourier transform, but can't figure out this lower bound.

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this helps. Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am not sure this is what I was looking for though. But I figured something: assuming $f$ satisfies homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions on both ends of the period's interval. Considering its odd extension one can take the Fourier series of $f$ which is then the sine transform: $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \hat{f}(k_n) \sin(k_n x).$$ Then the lowest frequency is $k_1=\frac{\pi}{L}$, with $L$ the period. I believe that is what is meant in the statement I quoted.

Comment: Note that here you are handling a mesh size $h$. This is the reason of my hint.